# Order WP_Query Posts with custom meta_key in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

So I want to order my posts with the meta_key start_date.

That is the code I'm using:

```
$main_query = new WP_Query(array(
'post_type'         => 'event',
'post_status'       => 'publish',
'orderby'           => 'meta_value',
'order'             => 'ASC',
'meta_key'          => 'start_date',
'paged'             => $cur_page,));
```

And that is an example of a meta_key value I want to sort the posts by:

```
meta_id post_id meta_key    meta_value
12397   31      start_date  1427830200
```

It doesn't work (sort)

Can you maybe tell me what I do wrong?

Comment: Thank you for your feedback! Can you maybe tell me how the meta query would look like in this example? I think it also would help other readers with the same problem.

Comment: refer this link https://wordpress.org/support/topic/query-date-array-to-display-future-events-only